# Merge n files using a C program

Tags: c

I am writing a download Accelerator. So I download a file from the webserver into n parts. Now I want to merge the files into 1 single file. So I use the following code. And the file names are in the correct order. But the output file I am getting is different from the original download file. Can you tell me where could the error be ?C

```
int cbd_merge_files(const char** filenames, int n, const char* final_filename) {

  FILE* fp = fopen(final_filename, "wb");

  if (fp == NULL) return 1;

  char buffer[4097];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    const char* fname = filenames[i];

    FILE* fp_read = fopen(fname, "rb");

    if (fp_read == NULL) return 1;

    int n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 4096, fp_read))) {

        int k = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, fp);

        if (!k) return 1;
    }
    fclose(fp_read);

 }

 fclose(fp);

 return 0;
}
```

Adding a few more details. The error is not in partitioning, since I am able to do "cat *.part > final.dmg" and the final.dmg works and is same as the original.

Comment: What happens when you run this on 5 files, each of 5 characters of the alphabet? Compare the resulting file with the expected output of 25 characters. What's the difference?

Comment: Why do you need to copy 5 files anyway? Create one file, reserve the complete size, and create 5 memory mappings into the same file at different offsets. Not only much faster, but also uses only half as much storage, and therefore less likely to fail with "disk full".

Comment: Also, you don't need an extra byte for your buffer. `fread` doesn't add a null byte (which I'm assuming what the extra byte is for).

Comment: maybe the bug is in the splitting, not in merging... (and `sizeof(char)` is always 1)

Comment: It works on me for the text files too. Splitting is not an issue as I am able to do "cat *.part* > final.dmg" and it works.

Comment: @Damon Will try the memory mapping. But Still I would like to know the issue in this. And Can anyone point me if fread will read the EOF character too ?

Comment: Amal: There is no "EOF character". The operating system keeps track of the size of the file, and stops reading at the end. (Functions that read characters from a file can return the value EOF instead of a character when the end of the file is reached, but it isn't actually a character, and it is not present in the content of the file.)

Comment: Please try printing the name of each file you are processing in your loop to make sure the files are being processed in the same order as your `cat` example.

Comment: Sorry guys. It was a very different issue. file pointer to the final part was not getting closed by the time I was merging the file. So the last part was different and thus causing the issue. Thanks for the time. I am voting up the answers that helped me debug and look into issues.

Answer (score 5):

Your function seems to work ok for me, so it might well be that the problem is in the input files of this function. In general, if you run across this type of problems in the output, it is worth testing each function in isolation to find out exactly where the problem is. The function you have in there is easily testable on its own, for example:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  cbd_merge_files(argv+1, argc-1, "output.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

I tried running your function with two files having "123" and "321" in them and it produced correct output in output.txt.

Answer (score 2):

The function looks correct (and Jari verified it for you). If you are sure your input files are not the issue (which you said you verified by doing a `cat *.part` in your comments), then you may have passed incorrect arguments to the function call.

Check that the array of `filenames` provided to the function match your expectations. Check to see that:

- The files are in the order you expect
- There are no "extra" files or "missing" files
- Each file name itself is what you expect

Check the number of file names in the `n` parameter is correct as well. Note that the problem might look like an extra or missing file or improperly named file, when it might be that the `n` parameter is wrong.

In your comment when you tested the files you downloaded by using `cat *.part`, use `echo *.part` to see the order that is being generated by the shell for your `cat` command.